# posts_per_page - Repeats only first posts 'post__in' array

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, get-posts, array

This question correlates with a previous question I was able to solve here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137929/28389

I am using an array for '`post__in`', and I am able to run this no problem.

However, when I am looping the posts with the default '10 posts per page', everytime the next page loads, it loads the first 10 posts over and over again. Not going on to 11-20, 21-30, etc etc.

My array consists of 100 post id's.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  'order_by' => 'post__in',
  'post__in'  => $post_ids, // This is an array of 100 post id's
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if (have_posts()) :
   usort($wp_query->posts, function($a, $b) use ($post_ids) { // Lists loop in order of the array -> http://pastebin.com/3vwiDSfb
      return array_search($a->ID, $post_ids) - array_search($b->ID, $post_ids);
   });
   while(have_posts()) : the_post();
     ...   
   endwhile;    
endif;
```

So when I use '`posts_per_page = -1`', or '`nopaging = true`', all 100 posts from the array displays fine. But I need the `posts_per_page` option' for lazy loading reasons.

---

Updated working code:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; // setup pagination

$args = array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  'orderby' => 'post__in',
  'post__in'  => $post_ids,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
     ...  
   endwhile;    
endif;
```

Comment: There is no pagination functionality built into this code, not even an attempt at creating such. How did you expect pagination to work? Search this site for "pagination" and "paginate_links" and see if you can't get started.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, I did not think `pagination` was needed since I was using the same code for a similar loop, though not with using `post__in`. The loop for that displayed correctly, so I assumed pagination was not needed for this snippet. Nonetheless, you pointed me in the right direction and I achieved a solution to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you were altering the main query via `pre_get_posts` WordPress would handle the pagination for you. That is not the case with secondary queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the sort within the loop if you pass the correct `orderby` argument. You've got `order_by` with an underscore, where it should be `orderby`, no underscore.

You can then set `paged` to the page number you want, and `posts_per_page` to however many you want on each page. Right now you don't set a page number to retrieve, so you're always going to get the same set of posts.

Have a look at [pagination parameters on `WP_Query` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. The working code is placed here: [http://pastebin.com/4ebfNaCX](http://pastebin.com/4ebfNaCX)